Bitbucket flutter pipeline for building docker image fails
enter image description hereI'm trying to build a flutter app through a dockerfile and pushing the image to dockerhub , vut the build fails at the flutter web build step. I thought the problem was due to environment variables so i tried different methods to pass it , using artifacts also , the code might look redundant but im unable to figure out the exact cause of build failure .
This is my dockerfile :

FROM ubuntu:22.04 AS build-env

RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt-get install -y curl git unzip
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y curl git unzip libgconf-2-4 gdb libglu1-mesa fonts-droid-fallback python3

ENV TAR_OPTIONS="--no-same-owner"
# define variables
ARG FLUTTER_SDK=/usr/local/flutter
ARG FLUTTER_VERSION=3.19.3
ARG APP=/app

#clone flutter
RUN git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000 && \
    git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git $FLUTTER_SDK && \
    cd $FLUTTER_SDK && git fetch && git checkout $FLUTTER_VERSION

# setup the flutter path as an enviromental variable
ENV PATH="$FLUTTER_SDK/bin:$FLUTTER_SDK/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:${PATH}"

RUN flutter doctor -v
#RUN mkdir $APP

COPY . $APP
# stup new folder as the working directory
WORKDIR $APP

RUN  flutter clean
RUN  flutter pub get
RUN  flutter build web

## Run static html to nginx
FROM nginx:1.25.2-alpine

# copy the info of the builded web app to nginx
COPY --from=build-env /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose and run nginx
EXPOSE 80
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=5s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost || exit 1

Should i try using a different method to do this , first build the app using a different image and then push the docker image .
This is my pipeline :
image: atlassian/default-image:3

options:
  docker: true

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Build and Test
            script:
              - touch .env
              - echo API_URL=$API_URL >> .env
              - echo CRYPTO_KEY=$CRYPTO_KEY >> .env
              - echo CRYPTO_IV=$CRYPTO_IV >> .env
              - echo CAR_API_URL=$CAR_API_URL >> .env
              - IMAGE_NAME=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
              - docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ${IMAGE_NAME}
            services:
              - docker
            caches:
              - docker
        - step:
            name: Lint the Dockerfile
            image: hadolint/hadolint:latest-debian
            script:
              - hadolint Dockerfile          
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          script:
            - touch .env
            - echo API_URL=$API_URL >> .env
            - echo CRYPTO_KEY=$CRYPTO_KEY >> .env
            - echo CRYPTO_IV=$CRYPTO_IV >> .env
            - echo CAR_API_URL=$CAR_API_URL >> .env
            - IMAGE_NAME=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
            - docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ${IMAGE_NAME}
            - docker save ${IMAGE_NAME} --output "${IMAGE_NAME}.tar"
          services:
            - docker
            
          caches:
            - docker
          artifacts:
            - "*.tar"
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - echo ${DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD} | docker login --username "$DOCKERHUB_USERNAME" --password-stdin                     docker.io
            - IMAGE_NAME=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
            - docker load --input "${IMAGE_NAME}.tar"
            - VERSION="prod-0.1.${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}"
            - IMAGE=${DOCKERHUB_NAMESPACE}/${IMAGE_NAME}
            - docker tag "${IMAGE_NAME}" "${IMAGE}:${VERSION}"
            - docker push "${IMAGE}:${VERSION}"
          services:
            - docker

